# C# Linq double groupby need min/max for hourly values once per day

Tags: c#, linq, date

I have been playing around with this for awhile now and can't quite get the result I am looking for.

I have an object like this:

```
public class Point
{
    public string Tag {get;set;}
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

Each tag will have 24 values per day (one per hour). Data will look like this (Tag / Time / value):

```
x / 5-15-2015 - 0100 / 10 
x / 5-15-2015 - 0200 / 20 
x / 5-15-2015 - 0300 / 30 
y / 5-15-2015 - 0100 / 20 
y / 5-15-2015 - 0200 / 30 
x / 5-16-2015 - 0100 / 10
```

for example...

I would like to sort by Tag and date, then get the min/max/avg for the 24 hrs in each day. The goal is to create the following object.

```
Public class NewPoint
{
    public string Tag {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int LowValue {get;set;}
    public int HighValue {get;set;}
    public int AvgValue {get;set;}
}
```

where the resulting objests would be (Tag / Date / LowValue / HighValue / AvgValue):

```
x / 5-15-2015 / 10 / 30 / 20 
y / 5-15-2015 / 20 / 30 / 25 
x / 5-16-2015 / 10 / 10 / 10
```

I was having issues with:

```
group list by new {list.Tag, list.Time.ToString("d") } into dateGroup
```

I also think I am going to need two linq statements. One to group by the tag and date to find the min/max/avg for each tag/date, and another to grab date[0] (or the distinct date per tag) along with the min/max/avg to pass to the NewPoint object.

Advice is welcome, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for two statements at all... nor using a string conversion. Just use the key of each group, and the `DateTime.Date` property:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Tag, x.Time.Date })
                .Select(g => new NewPoint
                        {
                            Tag = g.Key.Tag,
                            Date = g.Key.Date,
                            LowValue = g.Min(x => x.Value),
                            HighValue = g.Max(x => x.Value),
                            AvgValue = (int) g.Average(x => x.Value)
                        });
```

The cast for `AvgValue` is required because the return type of `Average` is `double` - you might want to consider changing your property type instead.

Comment: From what i got, his date might have diferent hours, thats why hes converting to the string without hour

Comment: @RodrigoLópez: And that's why I'm using the `Date` property - again, there's no need for a string conversion here. (As a general rule, unless your goal is *actually* to produce text, don't use a string conversion. There's almost always a better way.)

Comment: one more question. I actually have a few more attributes in the NewPoint object that I am doing some if checks, and calling some helper methods to calculate. Can I add these if checks to the end of the .select statement, or do I have to loop through all the new objects again? It seems anything within the .select is pure mapping ( attr = blah)

Comment: @Shak3nNotStur3d: If you have another question, you should ask it in a new post.

Comment: Will do for future posts. Figured it out tho. Had to map the attribute to a ternary statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you're after methinks:

```
    public class Point
    {
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewPoint
    {
        public string Tag {get;set;}
        public DateTime Date {get;set;}
        public int LowValue {get;set;}
        public int HighValue {get;set;}
        public double AvgValue {get;set;}
    }

    public List<NewPoint> Summary(List<Point> list)
    {
        return list
            .GroupBy(p => new {p.Tag, p.Time.Date})
            .Select(grp => new NewPoint()
            {
                Tag = grp.Key.Tag,
                Date = grp.Key.Date,
                LowValue = grp.Min(p => p.Value),
                HighValue = grp.Max(p => p.Value),
                AvgValue = grp.Average(p => p.Value),                
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```

Note the average is a double so NewPoint is updated to reflect that.

Comment: Drat, preempted by Skeet! It was foolhardy to even think I wouldn't be!

Comment: Thanks for the response Gene.